# jQuery moving row to another table based on selection in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with multiple tables (one table per "Activity Type"). Their IDs are the "Activity Types". Each row in each table has a cell with a dropdown that allows users to select the "Activity Type" of the new table they'd like to move the row to.

The below js code does move a row from its original table to the table of the selected "Activity Type" chosen in the dropdown menu. However, after the row is moved, the selected value in the dropdown remains as the old "Activity Type". How do I go about setting the value of the dropdown to the new "Activity Type" that the row now belongs to?

```
$('.override-activity').change(function () {
    // get selected Activity Type
    var activityType = $("option:selected", this).text().replace(/\s+/g, '');

    // get selected row
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr").remove().clone();

    // insert selected row into new Activity Type table
    $("#" + activityType).find("table").append(tr);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the "change" event never completes on the select since you are removing it from the DOM.

You could do 2 thigs :

1. Use the on blur of the select
2. Just before you append the TR, you could set the value of your select like so :

   ```
   $(document).on('change', '.override-activity', function () {
       // get selected Activity Type
       var activityType = $("option:selected", this).text().replace(/\s+/g, '');

       // Get the original selected value
       var selected = $(this).val();

       // get selected row
       var tr = $(this).closest("tr").remove().clone();

       // Reset the value
       $('.override-activity', tr).val(selected);

       // insert selected row into new Activity Type table
       $("#" + activityType).find("table").append(tr);
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this works. However, once the row is moved to the new table and the correct Activity Type is re-selected in the dropdown, if I try to now select a different option, nothing happens. Is this because the DOM is now in some sort of "detached" state? Would I be able to keep moving the row around?

Comment: Exactyl, i have changed my answer to suggest a better way of doing the event binding.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like after where you clone the `tr` and before you append it.
`tr.find('.override-activity').val(activityType)`